# How to calculate marginal effects in mixed models

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, marginal-effect

```
library(lme4)
m1 <- lmer(resp ~ pred1 + pred2 + pred3 + (1|site), data = Xs)
mod.predictions1 <- predict(m1, re.form = NA)
plot(pred1, mod.predictions1) # plot 1

Xs$pred2 <- mean(Xs$pred2)
Xs$pred3 <- mean(Xs$pred3)
mod.predictions2 <- predict(m1, newdata = Xs, re.form = NA)
plot(pred1, mod.predictions2) # plot 2
```

Between `plot1` and `plot2`, what is the difference? If I want to show
how does my `resp` change with `pred1`, should I show `plot1` or `plot2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show how your outcome `resp` is related to `pred1`, you should go for the second approach, because in the first one the predictions you obtained are affected by changing values of `pred2` and `pred3`.

In general, you can something like this

```
plot_data <- with(Xs, expand.grid(
      pred1 = seq(min(pred1), max(pred1), length = 100), 
      pred2 = mean(pred2), 
      pred3 = mean(pred3)
))

preds <- predict(m1, newdata = plot_data, re.form = NA)
```

Comment: Since re.form = NA, that means that the random effect is set to zero in the fiited model when using the predict() function, so we are dealing with a "typical" (or "average") site.  Then the predict() function can be used as explained by Dimitris for the second approach to determine, for example, how the mean value of resp changes as a function of pred1 for a "typical" site for which pred2 and pred3 are known to have average values.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [ggeffects-package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ggeffects) to compute (and plot) marginal effects:

```
library(lme4)
library(ggeffects)
m1 <- lmer(resp ~ pred1 + pred2 + pred3 + (1|site), data = Xs)
pr <- ggpredict(resp, "pred1")
pr
plot(pr)
```

There's a vignette showing the basics ([here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggeffects/vignettes/marginaleffects.html)) and one that shows the specialties of mixed model ([here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggeffects/vignettes/randomeffects.html)). You can find an overview of all vignettes [here](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/).